# Handle Client-Side Url in ASP.Net 4.5 MVC 4 Router

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, angular

I am rewriting a ASP.Net 4.5 application to Angular2. When I try to refresh a ng2-Route, the browser goes to the server and can not find the url.

It's the same problem like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628536/asp-net-5-angular-2-routing-template-page-not-reloading). The solution there is only for ASP.Net 5. I have tried the following in my Route.config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "spa-fallback",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

But that does not work. Is there a way to handle client-side urls in ASP.Net 4.5?

Comment: Of course, you do have to put the routes in the same order as the linked to answer in order for it to work - a catchall route should always go last.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works, but only if I remove the defaultRoute (or maybe any other routes) in my Route.config