# Angular 2, MVC in the same project - Error when putting '/' at the end of the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm getting an error because when i put `/` at the end of the URL the angular 2 service is looking for the current URL plus the MVC `controller` URL,

For example:

Without `/`: `localhost/controller/action`

With `/`: `localhost/controller/controller/action`

this is my code:

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetItemNames()
{
    var response = await _client.GetAsync("invoiceitems");
    var items = new List<Item>();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, errors = new string[]{"Please refresh the page or login."} }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(result);
        }

        var itemNames = items.Select(i => new {
            code = i.plCode,
            name = i.name,
            searchText = i.name.ToLower()
        }).ToList();

        return Json(new { success = true, data = itemNames }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Angular 2 service:

```
private invoiceUrl = 'invoice/';

getItemNames(): Observable<any> {
    const itemsUrl = this.invoiceUrl + 'getitemnames';
    return this.http.get(itemsUrl)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
        // TODO: Catch errors.
}
```

TIA :)

Comment: How are your routes defined? Have you set the [base href](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-base-href) element?

Comment: @elvin no, i did not use routes because i think i don't need that because of the structure of this project. can you specify an answer on how to use routes?

Comment: sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: np, you can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628536/asp-net-5-angular-2-routing-template-page-not-reloading there are different approaches mentioned there.

Comment: @elvin thank you, i fixed the problem by putting `<base href="/">`

Comment: awesome, you should put that as an answer to help others with the same issue.